# Trigger by Windows task scheduler

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-express, taskscheduler

I am developing a web application with ASP.NET and SQL Server Express and I want to check a status in database. After two days data is saved, if status is not changed, I want to call another function like `SendEmail()`. I have to use Windows Task Scheduler, I researched it but it seems for C++ developers. How can I relate Windows Task Manager and SQL Server Express, and how can I control a specific value for each row in a table?

Comment: The Windows Task Scheduler has got absolutely nothing to do with any programming language. It simply invokes an executable at a specified time.  In my office, we build mostly ASP.NET MVC web applications and we have loads of tools created a Console applications written in C# that we invoke via Task Scheduler. So, write whatever application you want and ten open Task Scheduler via the Control Panel and create a task to run it. That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want a long running c# application, either a console app that doesn't go away, or a windows service that runs using windows services.

In that app, you connect to your DB, do your query, and act on it how you'd like.

The other option is to write a normal c# app, that queries the DB, acts on the result. Then, simply schedule it in your windows scheduler (by hand) to run on whatever interval you'd like.

Comment: Thank you but i do not understand how can i link windows task scheduler and a specific value for each row in a table

Comment: I don’t understand. Your c# app is the only thing that needs to communicate with sql.

Comment: I can not explain you. How can I get contact between sql server express and windows task scheduler not c# between sql

Comment: What exactly do you plan to get from the sql server? What will you do with the data that you get?

Comment: User enter some data and admin must approve this. If admin does not approve in two days i want to send an email to admin. When user send his data, its status AdminApproval, data's status should not be AdminApproval more than two days.

Comment: Ok so what I said before is what you need to do. Either write a widows service or a normal c# app and run it on a schedule. You’re focusing on scheduler and Windows when that’s not a concern. Write a c# app that can do what you need. And have it run on a schedule at like 10 minute intervals or something.